# I get "ONNX/omp.h file not found" after I add the ONNX iOS runtime to my Xcode project?

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime

I'm trying to add an ONNX AI model and the ONNX runtime .xcframework to my Xcode static lib swift .xcodeproj project.

But when I build I get error:

> ONNX/omp.h file not found

I created a Podfile ("pod init" and "pod install") in the folder with the .xcodeproj and inserted the ONNX references into it (below) and did "pod update". (This created the .xcframework project)

I dragged the onnxruntime.xcframework into the .xcodeproj project and it appears in the nav pane.

Podfile..............

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Private' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Private
  pod 'onnxruntime-mobile-c'  # mobile package
  pod 'onnxruntime-mobile-objc'  # mobile package

end
```

Comment: I suggest you remove one of the dependencies (you can choose which, depending on whether you want to implement with C++ or Obj-C) - and see if the issue resolves.